# Returning 1 or 0 instead of value or null in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my `SELECT` statement, I join two tables. It's possible that there's no corresponding value in `Table2` in which case, my `SELECT` statement should return `NULL` for that column. What I want to do is that instead of returning the actual value coming from `Table2` I want to return a 1.

I thought I could use `ISNULL` for this but that function is designed to return the actual value if one exists.

This is what my `SELECT` statement looks like:

```
SELECT a.Id, ISNULL(b.PersonId, 0)
FROM Table1 AS a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Here the `PersonId` column is of `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type and I don't want to return either a `Guid` or a 0. Instead, I'd like to return a 1 or a 0.

How can I handle this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [`CASE EXPRESSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) here.

```
SELECT a.Id, CASE WHEN b.PersonId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Table1 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as @DaleK's excellent answer, another option is using `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT
    a.Id,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM Table2 AS b
        WHERE a.Id = b.Id)
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Table1 AS a
```

Note that the semantic is different here, as it is a semi-join: the rows are not duplicated if there are multiple matches in `Table2`